# The outermost for loop does not work as intended

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-12.04

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with GCC to compile my the codes for my assignment for a while. However, recently I have run into two issues as follows:

1. The following code calculates zero for a nonzero value with the second formula is used.
2. There is a large amount of error in the calculation of the integral of the standard normal distribution from 0 to 5 or larger standard deviations.

How can I remedy these issues? I am especially obsessed with the first one. Any help or suggestion is appreciated. thanks in advance.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 599
long double
factorial(long double n)
{
    //Here s is the free parameter which is increased by one in each step and
    //pro is the initial product and by setting pro to be 0 we also cover the
    //case of zero factorial.
    int s = 1;
    long double pro = 1;
    //Here pro stands for product.
    if (n < 0)
        printf("Factorial is not defined for a negative number \n");
    else {
    while (n >= s) { 
    pro *= s;
    s++;
    }
    return pro;
    }
}
int main()
{
    // Since the function given is the standard normal distribution
    // probability density function we have mean = 0 and variance = 1.
    // Hence we also have z = x; while dealing with only positive values of 
    // x and keeping in mind that the PDF is symmetric around the mean.
    long double * summand1 = malloc(N * sizeof(long double));
    long double * summand2 = malloc(N * sizeof(long double));
    int p = 0, k, z[5] = {0, 3, 5, 10, 20};
    long double sum1[5] = {0}, sum2[5] =  {0} , factor = 1.0;
    for (p = 0; p <= 4; p++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k <=  N; k++)
        {
            summand1[k] = (1 / sqrtl(M_PI * 2) )* powl(-1, k) * powl(z[p], 2 * k + 1) / ( factorial(k) * (2 * k + 1) * powl(2, k)); 
            sum1[p] += summand1[k];
        }
        //Wolfamalpha site gives the same value here

        for (k = 0; k <=  N; k++)
        {
            factor *= (2 * k + 1);
            summand2[k] = ((1 / sqrtl(M_PI * 2) ) * powl(z[p], 2 * k + 1) / factor);
            //printf("%Le \n", factor);
            sum2[p] += summand2[k];
        }
        sum2[p] = sum2[p] * expl((-powl(z[p],2)) / 2);
    }
    for (p = 0; p < 4; p++)
    {
    printf("The sum obtained for z between %d - %d \
    \nusing the first formula is %Lf \n", z[p], z[p+1], sum1[p+1]);
    printf("The sum obtained for z between %d - %d \
    \nusing the second formula is %Lf \n", z[p], z[p+1], sum2[p+1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**The working code without the outermost for loop is**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 1200
long double
factorial(long double n)
{
    //Here s is the free parameter which is increased by one in each step and
    //pro is the initial product and by setting pro to be 0 we also cover the
    //case of zero factorial.
    int s = 1;
    long double pro = 1;
    //Here pro stands for product.
    if (n < 0)
        printf("Factorial is not defined for a negative number \n");
    else {
    while (n >= s) { 
    pro *= s;
    s++;
    }
    return pro;
    }
}
int main()
{
    // Since the function given is the standard normal distribution
    // probability density function we have mean = 0 and variance = 1.
    // Hence we also have z = x; while dealing with only positive values of 
    // x and keeping in mind that the PDF is symmetric around the mean.
    long double * summand1 = malloc(N * sizeof(long double));
    long double * summand2 = malloc(N * sizeof(long double));
    int k, z = 3;
    long double sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, pro = 1.0;
    for (k = 0; k <=  N; k++)
    {
        summand1[k] = (1 / sqrtl(M_PI * 2) )* powl(-1, k) * powl(z, 2 * k + 1) / ( factorial(k) * (2 * k + 1) * powl(2, k)); 
        sum1 += summand1[k];
    }
    //Wolfamalpha site gives the same value here
    printf("The sum obtained for z between 0-3 using the first formula is %Lf \n", sum1);
      for (k = 0; k <=  N; k++)
    {
        pro *= (2 * k + 1);
        summand2[k] = ((1 / sqrtl(M_PI * 2) * powl(z, 2 * k + 1) / pro));
        //printf("%Le \n", pro);
        sum2 += summand2[k];
    }
    sum2 = sum2 * expl((-powl(z,2)) / 2);
    printf("The sum obtained for z between 0-3 using the second formula is %Lf \n", sum2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is this `M_PI` ?

Comment: That is the mathematical constant Pi

Comment: Where it is defined? On my compiler it is causing an error: `M_PI undeclared...`.

Comment: I'm suspecting `factor *= (2 * k + 1);` where are you clearing `factor `? It is called `pro` in the working method. I suspect that you do not need to carry its value between different values of `p`

Comment: @odedsh Yeah the factor was the culprit I forgot to set it back to 1. After the inner loop terminates; however the accuracy problem persists. How can I remedy that one also? I think I cannot calculate factorials higher than 1750.

Comment: @haccks and anyone still wondering, `M_PI` and a bunch of similar constants starting with `M_` are defined in `<math.h>` in some unix variants (not the really early ones - starting with System V maybe). glibc also provides them, but not when compiling in standard-conforming mode, because the C standard didn't include them and didn't reserve the `M_` prefix, so they have to be hidden to keep the user's namespace clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite certain that the problem is in `factor` not being set back to 1 in the outer loop..

`factor *= (2 * k + 1);` (in the loop that calculates `sum2`.)

In the second version provided the one that works it starts with z=3

However in the first loop since you do not clear it between iterations on p by the time you reach z[2] it already is a huge number.

EDIT: Possible help with precision..

Basically you have a huge number `powl(z[p], 2 * k + 1)` divided by another huge number `factor`. huge floating point numbers lose their precision. The way to avoid that is to perform the division as soon as possible..

Instead of first calculating `powl(z[p], 2 * k + 1)` and dividing by `factor` :
 - (z[p]*z[p]* ... . * z[p]) / (1*3*5*...(2*k+1))`

rearrange the calculation:   (z[p]/1) * (z[p]^2/3) * (z[p]^2/5) ... (z[p]^2/(2*k+1))

You can do this in sumand2 calculation and a similar trick in summand1

Comment: Well thanks for the comment I will provide feedback shortly after.

Comment: I am grateful your proposal solved the issue. However the convergence problem of the series persist, is there a way to make the series converge more easily?

Comment: I cleared sum1 and sum2 at the end but for z = 10 and 20 the sum gets really large in the first approximation. By the way these infinite series formulas are from Abramowitz and Stegun: Handbook of Mathematical Functions.

Comment: The same problem goes for the sum than as far as I understood. Then I shall set them back to zero at the proper place.

Comment: Thanks, will try and inform you of the results.